# Different column widths using multicol with pictures and text

Tags: multicol, width

Is it possible to specify different column widths in a multicol environment? For example, in a three column layout, can the left column be set to 0.16, the center column be set to 0.64 and the right to 0.16?

I tried with

```
 \begin{vwcol}[widths={0.16,0.62, 0.16},
 sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em] 
 \lipsum[1-8] 
    \begin{minipage}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=15cm]{ysm.png} % Logo or a photo of you, adjust its dimensions here
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}
        \veryHuge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Evaluating Longitudinal Biomarkers in NonLinear Models} \color{Black}\\[5mm]  % A bit of extra whitespace between the header and poster content
        \Huge\textit{An example of Sepsis and C-Reactive Protein (CRP)}\\[5mm] % Subtitle
        \large \textbf{Rosa C. S. Oliveira$^{1,2}$, Teixeira Pinto, A.$^{1,3}$, Raymond J. Carroll$^{4}$}\\ % Author(s)
        \footnotesize 1.Center for Research in Health Tecnologies and Information Systems ? CINTESIS | Faculty of Medicine, University of Porto, Porto, Portugal 2.  Superior School of Health Tecnologie Education of Porto, Polytechnic Institut of Porto, Porto, Portugal (rcoliveira@med.up.pt) 3.  Sydney School of Public Health, Sydney, Australia.  4. Department of Statistics, Texas A\&M University, College Station, Texas, USA
\\ % University/organization
    \end{minipage}


    \begin{minipage}{0.16\linewidth}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{logo_estsp.png} % Logo or a photo of you, adjust its dimensions here
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{logo_cintesis.png} % Logo or a photo of you, adjust its dimensions here
            \end{multicols}
        \includegraphics[width=20cm]{logo_atm.png} % Logo or a photo of you, adjust its dimensions here

    \end{minipage}

%\end{multicols}

 \end{vwcol}
```

but I guess this is just for text :(

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code to form a small, entire document. Right now, we have to guess your document class, relevant packages etc. ( What defines `vwcol`? `multicols`? `\veryHuge`? etc.?) Also, what happens which shouldn't? Or what doesn't which should? Does this have anything to do with `flowfram`?

Comment: Why do you need the columns at all? Why not just the minipages? How big is your paper?!

Comment: I haven't finished the code, but the beginning is just as follows:

Answer (score 0):

I did nit finished the code
I tried lots of possibilities, with multicols, columns, vwcol, without anything, ....
now the beginning is:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FOOTER TEXT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\leftfoot}{http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com} % Left footer text

\newcommand{\rightfoot}{rco@med.up.pt} % Right footer text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%define math commands
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\balpha}{\mbox{\boldmath $\alpha$}}
\newcommand{\bbeta}{\mbox{\boldmath $\beta$}}
\newcommand{\bgamma}{\mbox{\boldmath $\gamma$}}
\newcommand{\bmu}{\mbox{\boldmath $\mu$}}

\def\wh{\widehat}
\def\wt{\widetilde}
\def\X{{\cal X}}
\def\bfX{{\bf X}}
\def\bfW{{\bf W}}
\def\bfU{{\bf U}}
\def\bfX{{\bf X}}

\usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage{vwcol}  



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\color{Navy} % Navy color for the text


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%               Background                     %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\background}[3]{\leavevmode%
  \newrgbcolor{cgradbegin}{#1}%
  \newrgbcolor{cgradend}{#2}%
  \psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradend=cgradend,
  gradbegin=cgradbegin,gradmidpoint=#3]
  (-1in,3.5in)(\paperwidth,-\paperheight)}



   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%%                Poster                        %%%
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{poster}
 {\noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth}}
 {\end{minipage}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                pcolumn                       %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newenvironment{pcolumn}[1]{%
 \begin{minipage}[t]{#1\textwidth}
 \begin{center}%
  }{%
  \end{center}%
  \end{minipage}%
 }





%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   POSTER HEADER 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The header is divided into three boxes:
% The first is 16%% wide and houses a logo for the conference
% The second is 64%% wide and houses contact information
% The third is 16% wide and houses a logo for the universities/organization 




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%% HELP
%                                    having a problem defining the spaces for each element :)
%                                    can I set a background image?


\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.16,0.62, 0.16},
 sep=.8cm, justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em] 
 \lipsum[1-8] 
    \begin{minipage}{0.16\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=15cm]{ysm.png} % Logo or a photo of you, adjust its dimensions here
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}
        \veryHuge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Evaluating Longitudinal Biomarkers in NonLinear Models} \color{Black}\\[5mm]  % A bit of extra whitespace between the header and poster content
        \Huge\textit{An example of Sepsis and C-Reactive Protein (CRP)}\\[5mm] % Subtitle
        \large \textbf{Rosa C. S. Oliveira$^{1,2}$, Teixeira Pinto, A.$^{1,3}$, Raymond J. Carroll$^{4}$}\\ % Author(s)
        \footnotesize 1.Center for Research in Health Tecnologies and Information Systems ? CINTESIS | Faculty of Medicine, University of Porto, Porto, Portugal 2.  Superior School of Health Tecnologie Education of Porto, Polytechnic Institut of Porto, Porto, Portugal (rcoliveira@med.up.pt) 3.  Sydney School of Public Health, Sydney, Australia.  4. Department of Statistics, Texas A\&M University, College Station, Texas, USA
\\ % University/organization
    \end{minipage}


    \begin{minipage}{0.16\linewidth}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{logo_estsp.png} % Logo or a photo of you, adjust its dimensions here
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{logo_cintesis.png} % Logo or a photo of you, adjust its dimensions here
            \end{multicols}
        \includegraphics[width=20cm]{logo_atm.png} % Logo or a photo of you, adjust its dimensions here

    \end{minipage}

%\end{multicols}

 \end{vwcol}
```

Maybe it's no worth it ... but i really wanted to learn how to make a poster in latex.

Best,
RO

Comment: Please edit your question to include the additional information. It is fine to answer your own question - but only if you have an answer! Also, please be sure to start with `\documentclass...`. It *matters* that you are obviously not using `article`!